# Need to add row dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to add row dynamically once user click add more button. i use jquery to do this everything working fine but when i try to load value of select box which is getting from database and display inside loop. While i try to append that select box through jquery i got this error. Kind help in this.

Review this code and error message

```
<table class="table table-bordered form-horizontal"id="size_variants_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody
<tr class="control-group">
<td class="control-label">
<select class="form-control" name="product_size[]" id="mylist">
<option value="<?php echo 12;?>"><?php echo 12;?></option></select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="product_size_price[]" class="form-control"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="product_size_qty[]" id="product_size_qty" class="form-control product_size_qty"  onchange="valuecheck();"/>
</td>

<td><span id='removeButton' /><i class="icon-trash bigger-130"></i></span></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton' />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function () {

$("#addButton").click(function () {
if( ($('.form-horizontal .control-group').length+1) > 12222) {
alert("Only 2 control-group allowed");
return false;
}

var id = ($('.form-horizontal .control-group').length + 1).toString();
$('.form-horizontal').append('<tr class="control-group" id="control-group' + id + '"><td class="control-label" for="inputEmail' + id + '"><select class="form-control" name="product_size[]"> <option value="<?php echo 12;?>"><?php echo 12;?></option></select></td><td class="control-label" for="inputEmail' + id + '"><input type="text" id="inputEmail' + id + '" placeholder="Email"></td><td class="control-label" for="inputEmail' + id + '"><input type="text" id="inputEmail' + id + '" placeholder="Email"></td></tr>');
 });

 $("#removeButton").click(function () {
 if ($('.form-horizontal .control-group').length == 1) {
 alert("No more textbox to remove");
 return false; 
 }

 $(".form-horizontal .control-group:last").remove();
 });
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not an online debugger. Please visit the [help] and post effort. In this case look at the view-source and you will likely find a newline produced by the PHP

Comment: PS: if you change `append('.....')` with `append(\`......\`)` it may work better in newer browsers

Answer (score -2):

this may help you

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery add / remove textbox example</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    div{
        padding:8px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<script>

 var inpCount = <?php echo $yourdatabasevalue ?>;
     for(var i = 0;i<inpCount;i++){

           $('#your_div_where_you_want_to_append').append("<input type='text' name='pc"+(i+1)+"' /><br />");

       }
   </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: I am creating dynamic row once we click add button using jquery
The value which you have been seen is the value from database and show inside the drop down box. How can i append that select box using jquery append.

Comment: missing "when i try to load value of select box which is getting from database and display inside loop."